# Compare two JSON File and Merging Data in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, blazor

I have two JSONs files **Country** & **Ceremony**

Country JSON:

```
[
 {
   "Short": "AF",
   "Name": "Afghanistan"
 },
 {
   "Short": "AN",
   "Name": "Netherlands Antilles"
 },
 {
   "Short": "AI",
   "Name": "Anguilla"
 },
 {
   "Short": "AL",
   "Name": "Albania"
 } ]
```

Ceremony JSON:

```
[
  {
    "CName": "Fitr",
    "CStart": "2021-11-10T09:00:00",
    "CEnd": "2021-11-14T09:00:00",
    "Loc": {
             "Info": "",
             "Short": "AF"
    }
  },
  {
    "CName": "Azha",
    "CStart": "2023-06-17T09:18:44",
    "CEnd": "2023-06-18T09:18:44",
    "Loc": {
             "Info": "",
              "Short": "AI"
    }
  },
  {
    "CName": "Azha",
    "CStart": "2022-01-05T00:00:00",
    "CEnd": "2022-01-05T23:59:59",
    "Loc": {
            "Info": "",
            "Short": "AL"
    }
  },
  {
     "CName": "Fitr",
     "CStart": "2022-01-05T00:00:00",
     "CEnd": "2022-01-05T23:59:59",
     "Loc": {
             "Info": "",
             "Short": "AN",
     }
  }  
  ]
```

Country Model Class

```
public class Country
{
  public string Short{ get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Ceremony Model Class

```
public class Ceremony
{
  public string CName { get; set; }
  public DateTime CStart { get; set; }
  public DateTime End { get; set; }
  public Loc loc { get; set; }
}
```

Loc Model Class

```
public class Loc
{
  public string Info { get; set; }
  public string Short { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show Country (Name) with a connection to Ceremony, Loc, and Short, so that when I read the Ceremony data in front of Short, I can see the full name of the country. Country full name should come from Country JSON.

Results should be like this:

```
    CName CStart CEnd   Short        Name 
    Fitr  ""      ""    AF           Afghanistan
    Azha  ""      ""    AI           Anguilla
```

How can I use LINQ to display the top countries i.e., using (Short) with the most ceremonies in 2021?

Answer (score 2):

You can join two entities on `ShortName` like below :

```
var countries = ...;
var ceremonies =  ...;

var result = (from c in countries
             join ce in ceremonies on c.Short equals ce.loc.Short
             select new {
              ce.CName,
              ce.CStart,
              ce.Cend,
              c.Short,
              c.Name
            }).Where(r=> r.CStart.Year == 2021).
            GroupBy(r=> r.Short).Select(r=> new { Short = r.Key, 
           EventCount = r.Count()}).OrderByDescending(r=> r.EventCount)
           .ToArray();
```

**Edit**
Added grouping and sorting as the question evolves.