# Group By and Multiple Where Clause in LinQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

My data source has 3 columns **CYear** (Date Type),**Country** (100 Countries), and **Ceremony**. I want to compare the data for two countries (Pakistan & India) based on Ceremony in years 2010-2013

My Query

```
var que = (from e in dataset  
               where (e.country == "Pakistan" || e.Country == "India" 
               ||e.CYear == 2010 || e.CYear == 2011 || e.Start.Year == 2012)
               select e.Ceremony 
               // Group by for a total number of ceremonies each year
              // in the specific countries
              // to show to the user for better understanding
```

How can I compare the data for two countries and get the ceremony details i.e. total number of ceremony in these countries for the mentioned year.

I want to show the data in the table for a better understading of the data.

Comment: `e.country == "Pakistan" && e.Country == "India"` That won't fly. I guess the country cannot be Pakistan _and_ India _at the same time_. I guess you want `||` (or).

Comment: I have ceremonies in the data set for the specified time period both for India and Pakistan. I want to calculate the total amount each year for these two countries. or we could try with || too.

Comment: Each entry has _one_ Country, right? So, `where e.County == "Pakistan" && e.Country == "India"` would mean there need to be entries that have "Pakistan" _and_ "India" for "Country" which is impossible. If you do `where e.County == "Pakistan" || e.Country == "India"` then you get entries that have "Pakistan" and (other) entries that have "India". Same goes for the other columns.

Comment: @Fildor, the data set is in the form of JSON; this file has many objects containing data for different countries in different years. So that file contains data for Pakistan and India in the same year, too, but the objects can be up or down. so I want to fetch the data for specified year and count total number of ceremonies for each year for these two countries

Comment: @Fildor for reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75307918/compare-two-json-file-and-merging-data-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes exactly. Do you realize how the `CName` property is never two Countries _in the same object_? But that's what you filter for with `&&`. You want an "or" (`||`). Because _each object_ is _either_ Pakistan _or_ India (or neither). But _never_ both. It can't be. As well as they are in 2010 OR 2011 OR 2012 but _never_ all of those.

Comment: @Fildor ah i understand now. can you please post your snippet in the answer? thanks

Comment: I think you want `where ((e.country == "Pakistan" || e.Country == "India")  && (e.CYear == 2010 || e.CYear == 2011 || e.Start.Year == 2012))`, otherwise you will get results from other countries in 2010, for example

Answer (score 0):

```
var que = (from e in dataset  
           where (e.country == "Pakistan" || e.Country == "India" )
           && (e.CYear == 2010 || e.CYear == 2011 || e.Start.Year == 2012)
           select e.Ceremony `enter code here`
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

First fix the `where` clause, then group by country and year:

```
var que = (from e in dataset  
               where (
                   (e.country == "Pakistan" || e.Country == "India" ) &&
                   (e.CYear == 2010 || e.CYear == 2011 || e.Start.Year == 2012)
                )
               group e by new {e.Country, e.CYear}
          ).Select(g => new {g.Key.Country, g.Key.Year, Count = g.Count()});
```

Comment: @Muhammadzubair Typo. Try now.